# OpenLayers 3 multiple feature selection

Tags: openlayers-3, feature-selection

I would like to use a click interaction to select multiple features and show their division names.

Using the following code, If I add a new feature (using the Shift key) the infoBox2 is updated with the additional feature name (DIVISION) but it is repeated again in the infoBox2 when I try to remove this feature from the selection (with the altKey).

I whould like to deselect a feature and have its division name removed from the infoBox2. How is possible? Thanks

```
var infoBox2 = document.getElementById('info2');    

var selectClick = new ol.interaction.Select({   
    addCondition: ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly ,
    toggleCondition: ol.events.condition.never,
    removeCondition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly,
}); 

select = selectClick;  
map.addInteraction(select);

var features = select.getFeatures();    
var info = [];

var displayFeatureInfoClick = function(pixel) {
    var features = [];
    map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(pixel, function(feature, layer) { 
        features.push(feature); 
    });

    if ( features.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0, ii = features.length; i < ii; ++i) {
            info.push(features[i].get('DIVISION'));
        }
        infoBox2.innerHTML = info.join(', ');
    } else {
        infoBox2.innerHTML = '&nbsp;';
    }
};

map.on('click', function(evt) {
    displayFeatureInfoClick(evt.pixel); 
});
```

Comment: i have a solution for a similar problem.  please advise: do you want to get the info from ALL features at a given pixel (like when you click on a position on the map?).  I have code that does that.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, you wish to keep track of (and display information about) the features currently selected by the select interaction.

If that's the case, don't handle the click events yourself. Use the events provided by [ol.interaction.Select](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.interaction.Select.html).

The select interaction emits a [ol.SelectEvent](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.8.2/apidoc/ol.SelectEvent.html) each time the selection changes. You could replace `displayFeatureInfoClick` with

```
select.on('select', function() {
    var info = [];

    this.getFeatures().forEach(function(feature){
        info.push(feature.get('DIVISION'));
    });

    infoBox2.innerHTML = info.length ? info.join(', ') : '&nbsp;';
});
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions...but nothing is displayed in my infoBox2. Is Something wrong with my ol.interaction.Select? I'm working with v.3.1.1

Comment: OpenLayers 3.1 did not emit that event from the select interaction. Upgrade to a more recent version if possible. Otherwise: The method of fetching the selected features from the interaction still works. You could listen to the map click event and still use the body of the function in my response (after changing "this" to a reference to your select interaction).

Comment: Sorry still not so clear (I'm quite new with OL). How to listen to the map click event?

Comment: map.on("click"... It's the last statement in your question.

Comment: ;) sorry for my stupid question and thanks now something is working but I'm trying to understand why the infoBox2 has a "delayed" effect and it is updated only after the second click . I mean after the first click the first feature is selected and nothing happens in the infoBox2, with the 2nd click (and so during the selection of the second feature) the infoBox is updated  with the name of the first selected feature

Comment: I'm guessing that your click handler is processed before the select interaction handles the same click event. Try setting a delay (using window.setTimeout), so that ol3 can finish processing the click before you check for selected features.

Comment: InfoBox still updated at second click. What is wrong?                                               `var selectedFeatures = select.getFeatures(); 
 map.on('click', function(evt) { 
 var info = [];
 window.setTimeout(function() {
    selectedFeatures.forEach(function(feature){  
        info.push(feature.get('DIVISION'));
    }); 
    infoBox2.innerHTML =  info.length ? info.join(', ') : '&nbsp;'; 
 }, 100);
}); `